# polymer - variable not change after ajax call

Tags: ajax, variables, polymer

```
file objs.json:
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "My obj",
    "description": "My obj Desc"
}
```

file my-element.html:

```
<polymer-element name="my-obj">
<template>
    <core-ajax id="ajax" auto url="objs.json"
            on-core-response="itemsLoaded" handleAs="json"></core-ajax>
    <p>{{obj.name}}</p>
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Polymer({
        ready: function() {
            this.$.ajax.addEventListener("core-response", function(e) {
                this.obj= e.detail.response;
            });
        },
        itemsLoaded: function() {
            console.log(this.$.ajax);//.response
        }
    });

</script>
```

why my `{{obj.name}}` not change!?!?!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<polymer-element name="my-obj">
<template>

    <core-ajax 
       id="ajax" 
       url="objs.json"
       on-core-response="{{itemsLoaded}}" 
       handleAs="json"
    ></core-ajax>

    <p>{{obj.name}}</p>

</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        ready: function() {
            this.$.ajax.go();
        },
        itemsLoaded: function(e) {
            this.obj = e.detail.response;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have u try your solution! if u try: itemsLoaded: function(e) {
            this.obj = e.detail.response; console.log(this.obj);
        }  U will see itemsLoaded: function not called!!!! my's this.obj still null ??? tks!

Comment: you need to add "{{itemsLoaded}}" on "itemsLoaded". See now

Answer (score 0):

I found my err:

```
<core-ajax id="ajax" auto url="objs.json"
        on-core-response="itemsLoaded" handleAs="json"></core-ajax>
```

should be:

```
<core-ajax id="ajax" auto url="objs.json"
        on-core-response="{{itemsLoaded}}" handleAs="json"></core-ajax>
```